# How can I express this in HQL

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, hql

I've been stuck with this query for some time now. The SQL returns the result that I want, but I cannot work out how to express the query in HQL.

Here's the **SQL**:

```
select      thread.ThreadId,
            thread.Title,
            thread.CreatedOn, 
            thread.ViewCount,
            thread.CreatedBy,
            thread.ForumId 

from Threads thread 
where 
    (thread.ThreadId in(select post.ThreadId from Posts post 
    where (post.CreatedBy=2 )))

AND

(2!=(select TOP 1 post2.CreatedBy from Posts post2 
        where (post2.ThreadId=thread.ThreadId ) ORDER BY post2.CreatedOn DESC))
```

I think I need to use DetachedCriteria to create the correlated subquery, but I'm having real problems.

Here's **where I am** so far:

```
DetachedCriteria latestPostInThread = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof (ForumPost), 
                    "post2")
            .Add(Expression.EqProperty("post2.ThreadId", "post.ThreadId"))
            .AddOrder(Order.Desc("CreatedOn"))
            .SetFirstResult(0)
            .SetMaxResults(1);
```

and for the main **query**:

```
ICriteria critMain = CreateCriteria(typeof (ForumPost), "post")
            .Add(Expression.Eq("CreatedBy",user.ID))
            .Add(Subqueries.Ne("CreatedBy", latestPostInThread));
```

This is clearly not correct - I need to get the userId from latestPostInThread in order to use it as my subquery, but I'm utterly stumped.

Any help would be hugely appreciated! I'm loathe to fall back to SQL for something that I'm sure is not particularly difficult to achieve in nHibernate.

Comment: What's your SQL trying to do?

Comment: Do you want to express it in HQL or Criteria? Your question mentions HQL but your partial solution is based on Criteria.